# Report Designer for vb.net using Visual Studio 2008 and a SQL 2005 back end database other than Crystal Reports

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportviewer, report

We are developing in vb.net using Visual Studio 2008 and a SQL 2005 back end database and are looking for a Report Designer that can be used to build reports and give the User the ability to modify and create reports once the software is sold and in use.

Answer (score 0):

Reporting Services [ReportBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155933(SQL.90).aspx)?